# JS DevTools profile has a lot of dropped frames

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I'm developing an application that draws a lot of things on the HTML canvas.
I have a lot of dropped frames in my profile, however, it has a lot of idle time in each frame and I don't understand why a frame was dropped.
[image: profile]

What are possible reasons for this behavior?

Comment: are you using webgl?

Comment: no, I'm using CanvasRenderingContext2D